# Can Laravel read and/or store nginx access logs to display potential unwanted web scans?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, server, access-log

I built and deployed a Laravel application on an NGINX server, on a vps. I wanted to know if there is a way to leverage the access logs from nginx within Laravel, so that I can display the requests to the server on a dashboard for an admin to see. This way, if there is a vulnerability scan like openvas running, the laravel dashboard could show the useragent, ip, uri, etc.

I have tried 2 or three packages that do this sort of thing for laravel (think one is made by Torann), but I did not like the file structure, felt limited on customization, and ended up finding myself hacking together something else to view what it was logging. I also could not find the migration file within the /database directory when running that package. I know in pure php I can do this kind of task pretty easily, but I wanted to take a stab at the laravel way.

Comment: If there is more context needed please don't hesitate to ask. Constructive criticism over just downvoting with no reasoning would be greatly appreciated